# How to override element.style?

Tags: html, css

I am editing a MailChimp newsletter template and am having an issue removing some padding (see image).

I have removed some padding from this line of code:

```
 <td valign="top" class="headerContainer" style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:10px;">
```

but this does not affect the content as the padding seems to be generated by element.style when the page loads.

Full code for the header section is below.

How can I remove the padding?

```
    <!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateHeader">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="templateContainer">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top" class="headerContainer" style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:10px;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnImageBlock">
    <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding:0px" class="mcnImageBlockInner">
                    <table align="left" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td class="mcnImageContent" valign="top" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; text-align:center;">


                                        <img align="left" alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/4ca693f814be731ac4d5dc5f0/images/490a75b1-274d-421a-bd88-ef1c23165352.png" width="140" style="max-width:140px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" class="mcnImage">


                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // END HEADER -->
```

Comment: have you tried using !important? ... like - padding-top:0px !important;

Comment: *"having an issue removing some padding (see image)"* Did you forget to attach the image?

Comment: Does removing the headerContainer class solve your problem? Granted it will cause other css issues, but I am trying to see if you issue lies in the attributes in that class.

Comment: thanks! i have spoken to Mailchimp about this. it turns out it's to do with setting embedded in their template which can't be overridden in certain circumstances - e.g when using a custom code block in their drag and drop interface.